# Handling Ajax requests (success, errors messageS)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

normally i dont work much with ajax and laravel, but in my laravel app i need to make some ajax requests, and also handling errors and feedback. I see many material but im looking the right and best way in hadling from the back-end to the front-end (php and js).

Here is my code js:

```
$(function() {

            $('.send').click(function(event){

                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{url('admin/posts/ajax')}}",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {'name':$('#name').val(), 'surname':$('#surname').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
                    success: function(data){
                       console.log("sucess");
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public function storeAjax(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'             => 'required',
            'surname'          => 'required'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->messages(), 200);
        }

    }
```

But is giving me 500 error, so hope someone can guide me in the best way in handling requests between laravel and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how do I use ajax to make post request in laravel...

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "url", //not the complete url, in your case it would be "admin/posts/ajax"
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){

            console.log("success");

        },
        error: function(data){
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            //print the errors
        }           
    });
});
```

And how do I handle it in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // Validate the request...
   $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email|required',
    ]);

    //store data into database

    //return some data if required
}
```

The route should be..

```
Route::post('store', 'YourController@store');
```

Comment: And how tdo you handle on laravel controller?